# HAProxy always returns 502 Bad Gateway but the backend responds

Tags: haproxy, 502-error, 502

I have a HAProxy 2.8.4 which is used to proxy multiple HTTPS services on multiple URL paths and several different backends, and also a PostgreSQL cluster over TCP. This is the full haproxy -vvv output:

```
HAProxy version 2.8.4-a4ebf9d 2023/11/17 - https://haproxy.org/
Status: long-term supported branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q2 2028.
Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.8.4.html
Running on: Linux 4.18.0-513.5.1.el8_9.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 29 05:21:10 EDT 2023 x86_64
Build options :
  TARGET  = linux-glibc
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = cc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfatal-errors -Wtype-limits -Wshift-negative-value -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference -fwrapv -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unused-label -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-clobbered -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-string-plus-int -Wno-atomic-alignment
  OPTIONS = USE_THREAD=1 USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_TFO=1 USE_NS=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1 USE_PCRE=1 USE_PCRE_JIT=1
  DEBUG   = -DDEBUG_STRICT -DDEBUG_MEMORY_POOLS

Feature list : -51DEGREES +ACCEPT4 +BACKTRACE -CLOSEFROM +CPU_AFFINITY +CRYPT_H -DEVICEATLAS +DL -ENGINE +EPOLL -EVPORTS +GETADDRINFO -KQUEUE -LIBATOMIC +LIBCRYPT +LINUX_CAP +LINUX_SPLICE +LINUX_TPROXY +LUA +MATH -MEMORY_PROFILING +NETFILTER +NS -OBSOLETE_LINKER +OPENSSL -OPENSSL_WOLFSSL -OT +PCRE -PCRE2 -PCRE2_JIT +PCRE_JIT +POLL +PRCTL -PROCCTL -PROMEX -PTHREAD_EMULATION -QUIC -QUIC_OPENSSL_COMPAT +RT +SHM_OPEN -SLZ +SSL -STATIC_PCRE -STATIC_PCRE2 +SYSTEMD +TFO +THREAD +THREAD_DUMP +TPROXY -WURFL +ZLIB

Default settings :
  bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Built with multi-threading support (MAX_TGROUPS=16, MAX_THREADS=256, default=2).
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports : TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
Built with Lua version : Lua 5.4.4
Built with network namespace support.
Built with zlib version : 1.2.11
Running on zlib version : 1.2.11
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
Built with PCRE version : 8.42 2018-03-20
Running on PCRE version : 8.42 2018-03-20
PCRE library supports JIT : yes
Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with gcc compiler version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-20)

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.

Available multiplexer protocols :
(protocols marked as <default> cannot be specified using 'proto' keyword)
         h2 : mode=HTTP  side=FE|BE  mux=H2    flags=HTX|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
       fcgi : mode=HTTP  side=BE     mux=FCGI  flags=HTX|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
  <default> : mode=HTTP  side=FE|BE  mux=H1    flags=HTX
         h1 : mode=HTTP  side=FE|BE  mux=H1    flags=HTX|NO_UPG
  <default> : mode=TCP   side=FE|BE  mux=PASS  flags=
       none : mode=TCP   side=FE|BE  mux=PASS  flags=NO_UPG

Available services : none

Available filters :
        [BWLIM] bwlim-in
        [BWLIM] bwlim-out
        [CACHE] cache
        [COMP] compression
        [FCGI] fcgi-app
        [SPOE] spoe
        [TRACE] trace
```

This is my config, with the unrelated Postgre stuff and other HTTPS URL paths omitted:

```
lobal
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin
    pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  dontlognull
    retries 2
    timeout connect 4s
    timeout client  30m
    timeout server  30m
    timeout check   5s

# Temporary detailed logging
   log-format "Client IP:port = [%ci:%cp], Start Time = [%tr], Frontend Name = [%ft], Backend Name = [%b], Backend Server = [%s], Time to receive full request = [%TR ms], Response time = [%Tr ms], Status Code = [%ST], Bytes Read = [%B], Request = [%{+Q}r], Request Body = [%[capture.req.hdr(0)]]"

    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend main
    timeout client 86400000
    bind :443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy.crt

    option http-buffer-request
    declare capture request len 40000
    http-request capture req.body id 0

    capture request header origin len 128

    # Many other URL mappings and other use_backend directives omitted here

    acl url_apigee path_beg -i /apigee-connector
    use_backend voda-apigee-conn-be if url_apigee

    default_backend deny_be

# Many other backend definitions omitted here

backend voda-apigee-conn-be
    balance roundrobin

    option httpchk
    http-check send meth GET uri /actuator/health

    server api1 x.x.x.x:8002 check inter 10s fall 3 rise 2 ssl verify none
    server api2 y.y.y.y:8002 check inter 10s fall 3 rise 2 ssl verify none

backend deny_be
    http-request deny
```

When I call the backend directly with cURL, I get HTTP 200 response, and it also does internally what is expected:

```
curl -vvv -k -w "@curl-format.txt" -X POST -H "X-API-Key: my-api-key-1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @apigee-conn-email3.json https://x.x.x.x:8002/apigee-connector/outbound-communication
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 8002 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: <omitted>
*  start date: Dec  8 07:51:33 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  7 07:51:32 2025 GMT
*  issuer: <omitted>
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> POST /apigee-connector/outbound-communication HTTP/1.1
> Host: x.x.x.x:8002
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> X-API-Key: my-api-key-1
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 344
>
* upload completely sent off: 344 out of 344 bytes
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Server: nginx
< Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2024 16:38:26 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Expires: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=YWLvqrZAAMHBgbOLK9Q-nz2vrxhs9mKw_Yt92lQ5.cgwcsmfuatapp1; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
< RequestId: 59d32aad-4294-4811-a385-a4e65d68065f
< Quota-Reset: 1709139600925
< Quota-Allowed: 10000
< Quota-Available: 9998
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* Connection #0 to host x.x.x.x left intact
{"id":"94440760","attachment":{"id":{"value":"DOC-20240228-173826-WNHPC"}}}

     time_namelookup:  0.000076s
        time_connect:  0.000414s
     time_appconnect:  0.026246s
    time_pretransfer:  0.026375s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  2.132503s
                     ----------
          time_total:  2.133572s
```

When I call the same through HAProxy:

```
curl -vvv -k -w "@curl-format.txt" -X POST -H "X-API-Key: my-api-key-1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @apigee-conn-email3.json https://z.z.z.z/apigee-connector/outbound-communication
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying z.z.z.z...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to z.z.z.z (z.z.z.z) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: <omitted>
*  start date: Jan 31 20:50:09 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 30 20:50:08 2026 GMT
*  issuer: <omitted>
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> POST /apigee-connector/outbound-communication HTTP/1.1
> Host: z.z.z.z
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> X-API-Key: my-api-key-1
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 344
>
* upload completely sent off: 344 out of 344 bytes
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 502 Bad Gateway
< cache-control: no-cache
< content-type: text/html
<
<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
</body></html>

* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (256):
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):

     time_namelookup:  0.000073s
        time_connect:  0.001454s
     time_appconnect:  0.023841s
    time_pretransfer:  0.023926s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  2.589714s
                     ----------
          time_total:  2.589899s
```

HAProxy log:

```
Feb 28 18:01:38 localhost haproxy[3223599]: Client IP:port = [a.a.a.a:34660], Start Time = [28/Feb/2024:18:01:36.068], Frontend Name = [main~], Backend Name = [voda-apigee-conn-be], Backend Server = [api2], Time to receive full request = [0 ms], Response time = [-1 ms], Status Code = [502], Bytes Read = [208], Request = ["POST https://z.z.z.z/apigee-connector/outbound-communication HTTP/2.0"], Request Body = [<JSON body omitted>]
```

I always get 502 Bad Gateway, however, the backend still fully executes the request as expected, and it says that it generated a response... at least I see the exact same log messages on the application level in both cases.

I noticed that HAProxy switches to HTTP/2, I tried to force HTTP 1.1 in HAProxy config with the alpn directive, and also in cURL command line with the --http1.1 flag, then it was HTTP 1.1, but still 502 Bad Gateway.

What could be wrong here?

----- UPDATE -----

After comment from AlexD I modified my logging, I basically added all %Tx parameters I could find, just added human readable names because I will never learn what is Tr and TR and Th etc:

```
log-format "Client IP:port = [%ci:%cp], Start Time = [%tr], Frontend Name = [%ft], Backend Name = [%b], Backend Server = [%s], Active time of the request = [%Ta ms], Time to establish TCP connection to the server = [%Tc ms], SSL handshake time = [%Th ms], Idle time before the HTTP request = [%Ti ms], Time to get the client's request = [%Tq ms], Time to receive full request = [%TR ms], Response time = [%Tr ms], Total session duration time = [%Tt ms], Status Code = [%ST], Bytes Read = [%B], Termination state = [%ts], Request = [%{+Q}r], Request Body = [%[capture.req.hdr(0)]]"
```

New log after this:

```
Feb 29 08:46:33 localhost haproxy[3388761]: Client IP:port = [10.215.30.29:37666], Start Time = [29/Feb/2024:08:46:31.067], Frontend Name = [main~], Backend Name = [voda-apigee-conn-be], Backend Server = [api1], Active time of the request = [2092 ms], Time to establish TCP connection to the server = [8 ms], SSL handshake time = [20 ms], Idle time before the HTTP request = [0 ms], Time to get the client's request = [20 ms], Time to receive full request = [0 ms], Response time = [-1 ms], Total session duration time = [2112 ms], Status Code = [502], Bytes Read = [208], Termination state = [PH], Request = ["POST /apigee-connector/outbound-communication HTTP/1.1"], Request Body = [<omitted>]
```

This seems like useful information. The termination state is "PH", which seems to mean that the response was blocked during header processing. Which is weird, I don't think our backend application returns any invalid headers, you can see the direct cURL request response above. I tried setting http-response strict-mode off in my frontend, but it didn't change the behavior. I also didn't find much further info on this "PH" termination state.

----- UPDATE 2 -----

I managed to enable the admin socket by calling systemctl reload haproxy, not sure why this was needed. But after querying "show errors", this is what it shows:

```
[admin@ccaas1t-postgres-t1 ~]$ echo "show errors" | sudo socat stdio /run/haproxy/haproxy.sock
Total events captured on [29/Feb/2024:11:24:00.722] : 1

[29/Feb/2024:11:23:53.236] backend voda-apigee-conn-be (#13): invalid response
  frontend main (#5), server api1 (#1), event #0, src x.x.x.x:60930
  buffer starts at 0 (including 0 out), 15627 free,
  len 757, wraps at 16336, error at position 665
  H1 connection flags 0x80000000, H1 stream flags 0x00004810
  H1 msg state MSG_HDR_L2_LWS(24), H1 msg flags 0x00011654
  H1 chunk len 0 bytes, H1 body len 0 bytes :

  00000  HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n
  00015  Server: nginx\r\n
  00030  Date: Thu, 29 Feb 2024 10:23:53 GMT\r\n
  00067  Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
  00095  Connection: keep-alive\r\n
  00119  Expires: 0\r\n
  00131  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\r\n
  00194  Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=nGfILjPozmcVahj831vf21a6BXIxgqElGlE8zxqA.cgwcsm
  00264+ fuatapp1; path=/; secure; HttpOnly\r\n
  00300  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n
  00333  Pragma: no-cache\r\n
  00351  X-Frame-Options: DENY\r\n
  00374  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n
  00407  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains\r\n
  00472  VFHU-RequestId: 20681405-102a-4eed-8eee-00ed8f3c37c8\r\n
  00526  VFHU-Quota-Reset: 1709204400244\r\n
  00559  VFHU-Quota-Allowed: 10000\r\n
  00586  VFHU-Quota-Available: 9999\r\n
  00614  Content-Type: application/json\r\n
  00646  Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
  00674  \r\n
  00676  4b\r\n
  00680  {"id":"94464170","attachment":{"id":{"value":"DOC-20240229-112353-OTXV
  00750+ J"}}}\r\n
```

"error at position 665". Position 665 is the colon (:) in the "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header. This looks okay to me, the size of the chunk is sent as 4b hex, which is 75 decimal, which is the size of the JSON. Also we are not constructing this HTTP response manually, it is done by a Java lib, so I'm pretty sure this should be okay.

Comment: Your non-standard log format doesn't include the session state and all timings. The response time -1 indicates that the request was aborted before the full response was received from the backend.  You can use `option log-separate-errors` to raise the log level on errors.

Comment: Thanks @AlexD I added more flags to the log and termination state of "PH" seems to indicate some header parsing error. I also added the log-separate-error, but it just duplicated the log in my haproxy.log file, so I dropped it.

Comment: You can connect to your stats socket `/run/haproxy/haproxy.sock` and check `show errors`.  You can also try [option accept-invalid-http-response](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.8/configuration.html#option%20accept-invalid-http-response)

Comment: Ehh... the option didn't fix it, and it seems it's also not listening on the socket file for some reason... it's not responding, and the master socket says there is something failed in the <reloads> column, and the "show cli sockets" is also empty. It seems there are more issues here, I'll spend some time debugging the socket so that I can query the "show errors". But it's strange that otherwise it is working correctly, and also no error in system logs, audit logs, startup logs, anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two headers `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` - one at position `00067` and another at `00646`. `HAProxy` expects only one.